# Nutch fetches just the URLs that exist in seeds file

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, information-retrieval

I am trying to crawl some URLs with Apache Nutch 1.11.
There are 7 URLs in my `seeds.txt` file, and I run the command :

`bin crawl -i urls crawl 22`

My problem is that with depth 22, I expect it to fetch quite a few number of pages. But today, all it does is fetching the exact same URLs that exist in my `seeds.txt` file and nothing more. And as weird as it sounds, yesterday the exact same files and properties ended up fetching 313 URLs. I didn't change anything since yesterday. Anyone knows what's going on?

The only thing that has changes is that yesterday I was using another computer. But since I am running the crawl command on a  remote computer, I don't think it has anything to do with it. Does it?

Comment: what do you get when you run the crawldb stats command? the urls might not be refetched because they already have been and are scheduled for later. BTW what you specify with 22 is not the depth but the number of iterations, it is often the same but not necessarily. Did you check the URL filters?

Comment: @JulienNioche thanks, I just realized that it's the number of iterations yesterday. And yes I checked the URL filters. The first time it worked with the same filters. Later I run the line as :
bin/crawl -w 5 urls crawl 25
I had also set the fetcher.max.crawl.delay and generate.max.count to -1, and it started fetching. So I'm not sure but I guess as you said it's about the scheduling. BTW, It is my first time using -w and it took so long so I'm guessing choosing 5s wasn't a wise choice.
About the stats I don't remember the exact numbers but for status 2(db-fetched) it was 7.

Comment: -w 5s should not be related to your problem. It simply allows you to crawl continuously even when no URLs are due for fetching. What happens is that it continues the loop and decrements the iteration counts if nothing's due for fetching which seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a crawl dump with the readdb command and check the nextFetchDate for the seeds or try a fresh crawl with a new crawldb and segments dir to see what happens.

Do the logs reveal anything interesting? Are the seed URLs actually fetched and if so how do you know they are?

Is the content of the seeds likely to have yielded different URLs from the previous day?

*fetcher.max.crawl.delay* is not related to the scheduling but is about how to behave when robots.txt files set a value so large that it is impractical.

The config you are after is

```
<property>
      <name>db.fetch.interval.default</name>
      <value>2592000</value>
      <description>The default number of seconds between re-fetches of a page (30 days).
      </description>
    </property>
```

i.e refetch a month later. Again, a crawldb dump will give you all the details about what happened to your URLs